# Consider an experiment whose sample space consists of a countably infinite number of outcomes. Show that not all outcomes can be equally likely.

Tags: probability, axioms

I saw this proof:

Let S be the sample space. $S = \{s_1,s_2,...\} = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \{s_i\}$
Suppose all outcomes are equally likely, $\Rightarrow$ $P(\{s_i\})=c>0$
$P(S) = P(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\{s_i\}) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}P\{s_i\} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}c = \infty$, which contradicts that P(S)= 1. Hence, not all outcomes are equally likely.

I would like to ask why we can apply the axiom that $ P(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\{s_i\}) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}P\{s_i\} $ here, since I thought this axiom only works for mutually exclusive events, and the question did not state that the events are mutually exclusive.

Edit: spelling error

Comment: Those events are mutually exclusive - that's built into the meaning of "sample space".

Comment: By definition, no two sample points are the same.

Comment: Oh I see! Sorry, I just started studying probability and I'm not very good at it :/. But thanks!

Comment: Is each $s_k$ an elementary event?

Comment: It is not stated in the question but I guess you can assume that it is